# 2d10/d100/Percentile Dice question

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

So rolling a d100, or percentile dice, you (typically) would roll 2d10, take one in the tens place and one in the ones place. Does this mean if I roll a 90 and a 0 (a 10) that I get 100? Does that not increase the chances of me getting a 100, since I could get it two different ways, or am I misunderstanding?

I believe I understand everything else about these dice. For instance, a 00 and a 0 are 100, a 30 and a 4 are 34, a 00 and 1-9 is 1-9, et cetera, but this one has me stumped.

Any feedback and help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62280/how-do-i-read-2d10-as-a-percentage) already contains a lot of details on how to read 2 d10 as a percentile dice. However I think a resume of what you find there is:

You don't have to add one d10 to the other you just read the tenth dice first and then the other, you also don't read 0s. There is only one exception which is 00-0 that you read 100.

To make an example:

```
90 and 0 you read Ninety
90 and 1 you read ninety one
0 and 2 you read two
```

Answer (score 1):

You read a '10' on the digit dice as 0. If you roll '90' and '0' you have rolled '90'. Getting '00' and '0' is the only exception to that, and is counted as 100.